# Uncaught ReferenceError: variableis not defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I have a button on a website which executes the below function `getAccountsToPanel` when clicked. The function calls the available Google Tagmanager accounts of the logged in user and places them into a panel. The function is part of the external javascript file gtm_api_handling.js

```
var accounts;
var accountClicks = 0;
var accountButtons ="";
function getAccountsToPanel() {
   if (accountClicks == 0) {
     var request = gapi.client.request({"method":"GET", ath":"tagmanager/v2/accounts"});
     request.then(function(response){accounts = response.result.account});
     accounts.forEach(function(elem){accountButtons += `<button class="accordion">Account: ${JSON.stringify(elem.name)}</button>`;})
     var x = document.getElementById("accountPanel");
     x.innerHTML = accountButtons;
     accountClicks = 1; // make sure this function is not doing anything again after its first execution
   }
}
```

However, on the first click of this button, I get the error message:

```
gtm_api_handling.js:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at getAccountsToPanel (gtm_api_handling.js:147) // this is line that begins with accounts.forEach in the above function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (page2.html:52) // this is the buttons position on the main html sheet
```

If I then either go to the console and see the contents of "accounts" or click on the button again (rerun the function), everything behaves like I would expect it to.

Has anyone seen this before? Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: First, the code you posted has a syntax error (`ath` is not properly surrounded by quotes). Then, the error is actually pretty clear: `accounts` is undefined where you're referencing it. You probably want to use it within the `request.then` callback.

Comment: Are you missing opening quotations for `ath"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises), it seems like you need to put the `forEach` into the `then` callback function. Something like this might work:

```
var accounts;
var accountClicks = 0;
var accountButtons ="";
function getAccountsToPanel() {
   if (accountClicks == 0) {
     var request = gapi.client.request({"method":"GET", "ath":"tagmanager/v2/accounts"});
     request.then(function(response) {
         accounts = response.result.account;
         accounts.forEach(function(elem){accountButtons += `<button class="accordion">Account: ${JSON.stringify(elem.name)}</button>`;})
         var x = document.getElementById("accountPanel");
         x.innerHTML = accountButtons;
     });
     accountClicks = 1; // make sure this function is not doing anything again after its first execution
   }
}
```

Comment: You are completely right. It does work, if I include the forEach method in the then callback function. Thanks a lot.